# How can I integrate kafka with wso2 siddhi

Tags: wso2, apache-kafka, siddhi

I have a problem integrating kafka to wso2 siddhi. I am able to create a kafka input adapter, but I am not able to "configure input kafka event adapter message properties" as provided in the documentation.

As referred in the documentation, I could not find the inflow in the data stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect Kafka from Siddhi using siddhi-io-kafka[1] source and sink. Please find a working sample here[2].

If you want to get started faster you can also use WSO2 Stream Processor[3] which has an Editor[4] that has support for developing, testing and debugging Siddhi applications.

[1]https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-kafka/

[2]https://github.com/wso2/product-sp/blob/master/modules/samples/artifacts/HelloKafka/HelloKafka.siddhi

[3]https://wso2.com/analytics

[4]https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Understanding+the+Development+Environment